# gnu assembler convert int to string

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, gnu

Newbie here. I'm using the GNU Assembler (GAS) in Linux. I simply want to print something else other than "Hello world" to the terminal. But if I print a number, nothing gets printed. Here's the code.

```
.section .data

msg: .ascii "Hello world"
msglen = . - msg
numericData: .long 1
numericDataLen = . - numericData
.section .text

.globl _start

_start:

movl $4, %eax
movl $1, %ebx
movl $numericData, %ecx
movl $numericDataLen, %edx
int $0x80
movl $1, %eax
int $0x80

.section .bss
```

As you can imagine, when I load ECX with numericData, I expect it to print out "1" in the console. Instead, I get nothing. Why, and how do I print it out?

Using NASM, we don't have problems with printing integers out, as evidenced here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_numbers.htm

P.S. NO, I do not want to use printf in C. I want to stick to raw, unadulterated assembly code. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Notice that your linked nasm code converts between ascii back and forth, which you don't do here. Also it only handles single digits. As such, it's hardly more than a print char.
You can achieve similar effect if you change `numericData: .long 1` to `numericData: .byte '1'`.

Otherwise you will have to write a binary to ascii conversion function.